# Compute number of occurrences in a column of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a single column that holds string values (Twitter screen names) such as "user1", "user1", "UserX", and I would like to count those values so that I can easily craft a bar chart out of it. So the result should be

```
value        occurrence
-----------------------
user1         2
UserX         1
...          ....
```

Please note, I only want to look for whole words, and not part words. For example, the words 'on' and 'one' appears in the word 'money' - I would not count this (i.e., only the word 'money' is counted).

Hope that is clear enough. What formula should I use?

Comment: Did you want to find words within words though? EG, if your spreadsheet only consisted of 1 word, which was blabla, do you want to see the results as shown in your post?

Comment: No, no words within words, maybe the example is abit confusing. "bla" and "blabla" are just two different values, could be "bla" and "blu", for example.

Comment: And lastly, what about capitalization - does that matter. How good are you with VBa? And are all the words just 1 word, or some 2 or 3 words long (sentences)

Comment: Sorry, as per my VBa comment, is it an option to export to Excel? Otherwise, try this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Comment: Capitalization doesn't matter, and it's always only one word (actually Twitter user names). Actually I am  wondering whether this cannot be solved without employing a script...

Comment: If you do spreadsheets often, I recommend learning a bit of scripting. Just a little can go a long way. Learning curve typically is hard at first until you get going but persevere :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the number of occurrence of a word in Excel 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/518632/find-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-word-in-excel-2007)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheet:

1. Prepare all unique items: `=UNIQUE(A1:A10)`
2. Count them: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,B1)`
3. Added them together: `=CONCATENATE(B1," ",C1)`

See example I've prepared: [Find the number of occurrence of a word](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGYxemE1M3FkcWd6aGgzODhrVG5VT2c)

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table (under Data) should handle this requirement very well:

[image: WA36643 example]

Applying default settings the control total and alphabetical sorting are automatic.